# How to export blender model to Metasequoia files(.MQO)

Tags: export

That pretty much all, I need to export the model to this type of model for a papercraft designer program that only uses this file format. Is there any way I can export it to this format or any plugin I need to install to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this plugin : meshIO, I've tried to install it and apparently it's working:

http://sourceforge.jp/projects/meshio/

After installation, you can export in .MQO file with file -> export

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the perfect answer I was looking for. I wish I knew how to look for plugins...

Comment: Just use the good key word. For this plugin I've just typed 'blender mqo export' on google. The first link was from somebody who was using this addon and explain how it work. That's all :)